# How to only add an object to my array when it fulfills certain requirements

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I'm developing a Twitter app and I'm having problems with adding tweets to an NSArray. The problem is I get the tweets, and all the content ok, but the last query i got is just for control, so it doesn't contains the object "tweet" (which is the tweet content). I have tried stopping it if it detects the control query but no luck. This is the normal search query:

```
See dictionary: {
    "created_at" = 1305363612;
    "from_user" = IamDeShayDenise;
    "from_user_id" = 123375840;
    "from_user_id_str" = 123375840;
    geo = "";
    id = 69326131068813312;
    "id_str" = 69326131068813312;
    "iso_language_code" = en;
    metadata =     {
        "result_type" = recent;
    };
    "profile_image_url" = "http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/1336852311/110302-003005_normal.jpg";
    source = "web";
    "source_api_request_type" = 33;
    text = "@LondonBlackk Yeah....and Yes I was With My Mommy and Nana!!! && Still Pulling All The Guys...LoL";
    "to_user" = LondonBlackk;
    "to_user_id" = 172117314;
    "to_user_id_str" = 172117314;
}
```

In that one I get the text object ok and I can read it. The problem comes when I get this:

```
See dictionary: {
    "source_api_request_type" = 33;
}
```

Or this:

```
See dictionary: {
    "completed_in" = "0.027116";
    "max_id" = 69324964586725376;
    "max_id_str" = 69324964586725376;
    "next_page" = "?page=2&max_id=69324964586725376&q=lol";
    page = 1;
    query = lol;
    "refresh_url" = "?since_id=69324964586725376&q=lol";
    "results_per_page" = 15;
    "since_id" = 1;
    "since_id_str" = 1;
    "source_api_request_type" = 33;
    warning = "since_id removed for pagination.";
}
```

And this is the code I use for filling the arrays:

```
tweets = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    usernames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for(NSDictionary *d in searchResults) {
```

```
     NSLog(@"See dictionary: %@", d);
     Tweet *author = [d objectForKey:@"from_user"];
     Tweet *tweet = [d objectForKey:@"text"];
     if ([d objectForKey:@"from_user"] == nil || [d objectForKey:@"text"] == nil){
         NSLog(@"end");
     } 
    [usernames addObject:author];
    [tweets addObject:tweet];

     [author release];
     [tweet release];
 }
```

I don't know what can be wrong :(

Thanks in advance :D

**UPDATE:**Got it working in this way

```
if ([d objectForKey:@"from_user"] == nil || [d objectForKey:@"text"] == nil){
             NSLog(@"end");
         } else {
             [usernames addObject:author];
             [tweets addObject:tweet];
         }
```

instead of:

```
if ([d objectForKey:@"from_user"] == nil || [d objectForKey:@"text"] == nil){
             NSLog(@"end");
         } 
    [usernames addObject:author];
    [tweets addObject:tweet];
```

Then the other problem was also solved. Thanks y'all!!

Comment: Uhm… is your `Tweet` class a subclass of `NSString`? That is pretty advanced stuff, yet juggling two separate arrays front he tweets and the users instead of a proper domain object.

Comment: What specific problem were you having? Also, please move your second question to a separate question.

Comment: Also, you are over-releasing the `author` and `tweet` objects. The dictionary owns its objects; retrieving them from the dictionary does not transfer that ownership to you. The dictionary will release them, as will the arrays; since you do not own them directly, you should not release them.

Comment: Finally solved it, will post the answer:

Comment: Please post the answer as an actual answer so the question doesn't show up as unanswered! It may even get upvoted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of solving it is this:

```
if ([d objectForKey:@"from_user"] == nil || [d objectForKey:@"text"] == nil){
             NSLog(@"end");
         } else {
             [usernames addObject:author];
             [tweets addObject:tweet];
         }
```

instead of:

```
if ([d objectForKey:@"from_user"] == nil || [d objectForKey:@"text"] == nil){
             NSLog(@"end");
         } 
    [usernames addObject:author];
    [tweets addObject:tweet];
```